# How to escape reserved words in Hibernate's HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I use the following query to get a `java.util.Map` with indexes `id`, `text` and `object`:

```
Query q = mySession.createQuery(
    "SELECT u.id AS id, u.name AS text, u AS object FROM User u")
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
```

... but `object` seems to be a reserved word. For example `obj` is OK. What is the current way to escape an *alias* in HQL the way MySQL uses backtick escapes?

Using backtick gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: 
'`' [SELECT u.id AS id, u.name AS text, u AS `object` FROM User u]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could achieve it by a workaround using your custom "alias to map" transformer, so your code would change to something like this

```
Query q = mySession.createQuery(
    "SELECT u.id AS id, u.name AS text, u AS obj FROM User u")
    .setResultTransformer(
        AliasToMapTransformer.renameAlias("obj", "object").build()
    );
```

And then using this class:

```
public class AliasToMapTransformer extends BasicTransformerAdapter {

    private Map<String, String> renameAliasMap;


    public AliasToMapTransformer(Map<String, String> renameAliasMap) {
        this.renameAliasMap = (renameAliasMap == null) ? Collections.<String, String>emptyMap() : renameAliasMap;
    }


    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>(tuple.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < tuple.length; i++) {
            String alias = aliases[i];
            if (alias != null) {
                String newAlias = renameAliasMap.get(alias);

                result.put((newAlias != null) ? newAlias : alias, tuple[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static Builder renameAlias(String alias, String newAlias) {
        return new Builder().renameAlias(alias, newAlias);
    }


    public static class Builder {

        private Map<String, String> aliasConversionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();


        public Builder renameAlias(String alias, String newAlias) {
            aliasConversionMap.put(alias, newAlias);
            return this;
        }


        public AliasToMapTransformer build() {
            return new AliasToMapTransformer(aliasConversionMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's the best solution so far.

Comment: This only works for working around names selected in a very specific way. What if you want to work around keywords written in a "where" clause or elsewhere?

Answer (score 6):

On a related topic, escaping a reserved word in a column name is as easy as prepending with a table alias. No backticks, square brackets, etc. Simply replace

```
select where from mytable
```

by:

```
select t.where from mytable t
```

(note: i'm NOT saying it's a good idea to have "where" as column name ;-)

Answer (score 2):

the back tics concept works in hibernate.. unfortunately this only works if you've done annotation config...

you can try to do this in a different way (without annotations).

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select new User (u.id, u.name, u.object) from User u").list();
```

here you need to create a constructor in use which accepts an id, name, object elements & in that order.

Comment: Backtics can be used in the XML mapping file too. But I want to escape things in HQL. The main point of aliases would be that they can be arbitrarily assigned. I'm using `Map` as the lowest common denominator between decoupled parts of the system. It would be really handy if only they worked.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i'm really late on this question but since the above solutions didn't work for me i thought i'd post the solution that did.

Our issue was a field named "row". The solution depending on xml or annotation would be:

```
@Column(name="`row`")
private String row;
```

```
<property name="row" column="`row`" access="field" not-null="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do backticks not work on aliases?
The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers) says to use them for fields.

Other questions:

- Is another value possible?
- Why a map (it also contains the original value) and not a List? 
  Id and Name could be retrieved from the original Object.

Comment: I tried ofc. They semmingly do not work in queries. I want to use map as it is quite felxible and the data is fed to an other API.