# Error in named query (QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token)

Tags: hibernate, named

I am currently working on a utility project which will help me to manage the users of an application (a user has one or more role, and a role has one or more rights).
I am new to Hibernate, and I don't know why I have encountered the following issue :

```java
ERROR [hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] HHH000177: Error in named query: right.findAllByRoleId
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: right near line 1, column 8 [select right from com.google.code.jee.utils.user.management.model.Role as r left join r.rights as right where r.id = :roleId]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1130)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1740)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:350)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:9)
```

Right class :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "RIG_RIGHT")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = RightDao.COUNT_BY_NAME, query = "select count(*) from Right as rig where rig.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = RightDao.FIND_BY_NAME, query = "from Right as rig where rig.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = RightDao.COUNT_FOR_ROLE_ID, query = "select count(*) from Role as r where r.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = RightDao.FIND_ALL_BY_ROLE_ID, query = "select right from Role as r left join r.rights as right where r.id = :roleId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = RightDao.COUNT_FOR_ROLE_ID_AND_NAME, query = "select count(*) from Role as r left join r.rights as right where r.id = :roleId and right.name = :rightName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = RightDao.FIND_BY_ROLE_ID_AND_NAME, query = "select right from Role as r left join r.rights as right where r.id = :roleId and right.name = :rightName") })
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Right extends AbstractHibernateDto<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "RIG_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "RIG_NAME", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 50)
    private String name;

       // Getters & Setters
```

Role class :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROL_ROLE")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = RoleDao.COUNT_BY_NAME, query = "select count(*) from Role as r where r.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = RoleDao.FIND_BY_NAME, query = "from Role as r where r.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = RoleDao.COUNT_FOR_USER_ID, query = "select count(*) from User as u where u.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = RoleDao.FIND_ALL_BY_USER_ID, query = "select role from User as u left join u.roles as role where u.id = :userId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = RoleDao.COUNT_FOR_USER_ID_AND_NAME, query = "select count(*) from User as u left join u.roles as role where u.id = :userId and role.name = :roleName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = RoleDao.FIND_BY_USER_ID_AND_NAME, query = "select role from User as u left join u.roles as role where u.id = :userId and role.name = :roleName") })
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Role extends AbstractHibernateDto<Integer> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ROL_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "ROL_NAME", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RIG_ROLE_ID", nullable = false)
    private List<Right> rights;

    // Getters & Setters
```

Right DAO :

```java
public interface RightDao extends GenericDao<Integer, Right> {

    public final String COUNT_BY_NAME = "right.countByName";
    public final String FIND_BY_NAME = "right.findByName";
    public final String COUNT_FOR_ROLE_ID = "right.countForRoleId";
    public final String FIND_ALL_BY_ROLE_ID = "right.findAllByRoleId";
    public final String COUNT_FOR_ROLE_ID_AND_NAME = "right.countForRoleIdAndName";
    public final String FIND_BY_ROLE_ID_AND_NAME = "right.findByRoleIdAndName";

    /**
     * Search the number of elements with the 'name' parameter.
     * 
     * @param name the name
     * @return the number of element found
     */
    public Integer countByName(String name);

    /**
     * Search an element by its name.
     * 
     * @param name the name
     * @return the right
     */
    public Right findByName(String name);

    /**
     * Count the number of rights of a specific role
     * 
     * @param roleId the role id
     * @return the number of rights
     */
    public Integer countForRoleId(Integer roleId);

    /**
     * Finds all rights by roleId.
     * 
     * @param roleId the role primary key
     * @return the list
     */
    public List<Right> findAllByRoleId(Integer roleId);

    /**
     * Count the number of rights with a specific name and corresponding to
     * a specific role
     * 
     * @param roleId the roleId
     * @param rightName the right name
     * @return the number of rights
     */
    public Integer countForRoleIdAndName(Integer roleId, String rightName);

    /**
     * Finds the right.
     * 
     * @param roleId the role primary key
     * @param rightName the right name
     * @return the right
     */
    public Right findByRoleIdAndName(Integer roleId, String rightName);

}
```

Role DAO :

```java
public interface RoleDao extends GenericDao<Integer, Role> {

    public final String COUNT_BY_NAME = "role.countByName";
    public final String FIND_BY_NAME = "role.findByName";
    public final String COUNT_FOR_USER_ID = "role.countForUserId";
    public final String FIND_ALL_BY_USER_ID = "role.findAllByUserId";
    public final String COUNT_FOR_USER_ID_AND_NAME = "role.countForUserIdAndName";
    public final String FIND_BY_USER_ID_AND_NAME = "role.findByUserIdAndName";

    /**
     * Search the number of elements with the 'name' parameter.
     * 
     * @param name the name
     * @return the number of element found
     */
    public Integer countByName(String name);

    /**
     * Search an element by its name.
     * 
     * @param name the name
     * @return the user
     */
    public Role findByName(String name);

    /**
     * Count the number of roles of a specific user
     * 
     * @param userId the user id
     * @return the number of roles
     */
    public Integer countForUserId(Integer userId);

    /**
     * Finds all roles by user id.
     * 
     * @param userId the user primary key
     * @return the list
     */
    public List<Role> findAllByUserId(Integer userId);

    /**
     * Count the number of roles with a specific name and corresponding to
     * a specific user
     * 
     * @param userId the userId
     * @param roleName the role name
     * @return the number of roles
     */
    public Integer countForUserIdAndName(Integer userId, String roleName);

    /**
     * Finds the role.
     * 
     * @param userId the user primary key
     * @param roleName the role name
     * @return the role
     */
    public Role findByUserIdAndName(Integer userId, String roleName);

}
```

Any idea ? Thank you in advance !
Julien Neuhart

Comment: try using different word inplace of right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the source of the error is using `right` as a variable name in one of your named queries (`RightDao.FIND_ALL_BY_ROLE_ID`, `RightDao.FIND_BY_ROLE_ID_AND_NAME`). `right` is a reserved word in HQL (`right outer join`)

Either:

1. Use different alias for `right`:

   > `@NamedQuery(name = RightDao.FIND_ALL_BY_ROLE_ID, 
   >     query = "select r from Role as role left join role.rights as r 
   >                  where role.id = :roleId"),
   > @NamedQuery(name = RightDao.FIND_BY_ROLE_ID_AND_NAME, 
   >     query = "select r from Role as role left join role.rights as r 
   >                  where role.id = :roleId and r.name = :rightName") })`
2. Escape the reserved word `right` in the query by surrounding it with square brackets `[right]`, or backticks. Also, you might fins the following related question useful: [How to escape reserved words in Hibernate's HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5686412/851811).

Comment: Well, I didn't know that `right` was a reserved word in HQL ! Thank you !