# HQL insert query with select, (unexpected token: order near line 11))

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails, hql

I am trying to write a query for insert with select.
but i am getting this error
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: order near line 11, column 23

```
Query query = hibSession.createQuery("""
              INSERT INTO
                  ProcessOrder(
                  version,
                  numberOfPeriods,
                  billingPeriodStart,
                  billingPeriodEnd,
                  invoice,
                  billingRun,
                  org,
                  order)
              SELECT
                  1L AS version,
                  1 AS numberOfPeriods,
                  ilt.billingStartDate AS billingPeriodStart,
                  ilt.billingEndDate AS billingPeriodEnd,
                  i AS invoice,
                  i.billingRun as billingRun,
                  i.org as org,
                  soi as order
              from
                  Invoice as i
                  join i.ordersIncluded as soi
                  join i.invoiceLineItems as ilt
              where
                  i.billingRun = 36 AND
                  i.status IN ('Outstanding','Paid')  AND
                  ilt.position = 1  """)
```

Please help to overcome this problem

Answer (score 1):

*order* is a **reserved** sql word.  Better not to use it as an alias.

On that line, use for example : `soi as soiOrder`
and of course also change in the insert order by soiOrder

You could also use:

```
.setResultTransformer(
    AliasToMapTransformer.renameAlias("soiOrder", "order").build()
)
```

With this class  (copyright :  [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5754720/1173560)):

```
public class AliasToMapTransformer extends BasicTransformerAdapter {

  private Map<String, String> renameAliasMap;


  public AliasToMapTransformer(Map<String, String> renameAliasMap) {
    this.renameAliasMap = (renameAliasMap == null) ? Collections.<String, String>emptyMap() : renameAliasMap;
  }


  @Override
  public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>(tuple.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < tuple.length; i++) {
        String alias = aliases[i];
        if (alias != null) {
            String newAlias = renameAliasMap.get(alias);

            result.put((newAlias != null) ? newAlias : alias, tuple[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
  }


  public static Builder renameAlias(String alias, String newAlias) {
    return new Builder().renameAlias(alias, newAlias);
  }


  public static class Builder {

    private Map<String, String> aliasConversionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();


    public Builder renameAlias(String alias, String newAlias) {
        aliasConversionMap.put(alias, newAlias);
        return this;
    }


    public AliasToMapTransformer build() {
        return new AliasToMapTransformer(aliasConversionMap);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean HQL, not SQL.

Comment: but my DomainClass has order field so i cannot change it with soiOrder.
Or if i change it then it gives this error
could not resolve property: soiOrder of class ProcessOrder

Comment: That is just an alias in your query. The alias name has nothing to do with your domain. Trust me. Change order 2 times by soiOrder. Just try it.  Trial and error.

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: soiOrder of: com.ProcessOrder [
INSERT INTO
ProcessOrder(
 version,
 numberOfPeriods,
 billingPeriodStart,
 billingPeriodEnd,
 invoice,
 billingRun,
 org,
 soiOrder)
SELECT
 1L AS version,
 1 AS numberOfPeriods,
 ilt.billingStartDate AS billingPeriodStart,
 ilt.billingEndDate AS billingPeriodEnd,
 i AS invoice,
 i.billingRun as billingRun,
 i.org as org,
   soi as soiOrder
from
com.blusynergy.blubilling.invoice.Invoice as i
join i.ordersIncluded as soi
join i.invoiceLineItems as ilt


Now this error comes

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Well you can use maybe this : .setResultTransformer(
        AliasToMapTransformer.renameAlias("soiOrder", "order").build()
    )   See my edited answer

Comment: i can change the alias select but cannot change the column name my column name is order.
and its giving error at the time of inserting
The way u suggest me to change the alias is for selecting time but what should do if its at the time of inserting 
INSERT INTO
                      ProcessOrder(
                      version,
                      numberOfPeriods,
                      billingPeriodStart,
                      billingPeriodEnd,
                      invoice,
                      billingRun,
                      org,
                      order)
So its giving exception here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41693/discussion-between-chetan-sharma-and-k-c)