# How to escape the keyword "on" in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hql

Here is my `Entity` which I want to query with `Hibernate` 4.3.4:

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class Device extends OrmEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "is_on") // was necessary to get Hibernate to create the table at all
    private boolean on;

    ...
}
```

This is the HQL I want to execute (btw the database is `PostgreSQL`):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Device where ... and on = :a");
query.setBoolean("a", true);
```

This gives me `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1`.

I tried many escape characters like backticks, \", [ ], single-quotes, without success.

What would be the appropriate way to escape the keyword "on" in this HQL-query?

**Edit:**

I tried `"from Device d where d.on = :a"` which results in `QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: d near line 1`.

I did not try `renameAlias` as this seems to be overkill for just escaping a keyword...

**Edit2:**

I am trying out `AliasToMapTransformer` but I can not seem to get it working for a `where` clause ... ? It seems to be made for column aliases.

**Edit3:**

Generally, this code is around for some time already and strangely it worked with `Hibernate` < 4.3.$

**Edit4:**

I accepted NimChimpsky's answer, and implemented the following change: Rename the boolean member from `on` to `isOn`, but keep the getter and setter as they were: `setOn()` and `isOn()`.

No further change in my code necessary, and `Hibernate` is happy now.

Comment: Have you tried `from Device d where d.on = :a`?

Comment: I'm sure there is some ugly way to escape the name of the variable. But honestly - naming a variable in your DAO the same thing as a SQL reserved word is a bad idea. Just rename the boolean.

Comment: Did you try `renameAlias` as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686412/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-hibernates-hql

Comment: I am still interested in the ugly way to escape the HQL... In naming my entity properties I tend not to think in database terms, but in business object properties, that's why I came up with "on" as property ... if (device.isOn()) {} just feels natural.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL, I added the info to the question right now. Note that I named the column "is_on" with the `@Column` annotation. The problem is as I believe purely HQL/Hibernate related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Column
private boolean deviceIsOn;
```

annotate the field with a renamed variable, and then my method would be `isOn`.

Bit hacky ... but you keep your nice friendly OO api, with out too much hassle.

Or even simpler, just call it `off` which isn't reserved