# Order by count in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I've got a field called "count". And now I want to order my table by that field. As I know, `COUNT` is reserved statement in Hibernate. Is there any approach to order table without renaming?
My code:

```
@Override
public List<Distribution> getListOrderByCount(String userName) {
    List<Distribution> result = (List<Distribution>) sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery(
                    "from Distribution where username=:userName ORDER BY count DESC")
            .setString("userName", userName).list();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Try using Criteria Queries or other solution is to sort it yourself... ;)

Comment: This might be helpful (similar problem on SO) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364835/automatic-reserved-word-escaping-for-hibernate-tables-and-columns

Comment: You can use Alias to map transformers. Might be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686412/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-hibernates-hql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this !

```
@Override
public List<Distribution> getListOrderByCount(String userName) {
    List<Distribution> result = (List<Distribution>) sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery(
      "from Distribution as d where d.username=:userName ORDER BY d.count DESC")
            .setString("userName", userName).list();
    return result;
}
```