# How to escape reseved words from HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a table name **Order** and since it is a reserved word in Hibernate, it is not letting me to construct desired query. Is there any way by which I can escape table name in HQL?

I got across similar question asking for alias [How to escape reserved words in Hibernate's HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686412/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-hibernates-hql)

But this solution is not working for me. Is there any other way by which we can do this? I am using version 4.3 of hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you mapped the table to an entity that is also called Order?  If so then I'd suggest renaming the entity as there as the Hibernate team appear to have [rejected the request to add keyword escaping to HQL](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3811).  If the problem is actually with the generated SQL then you can add backticks to the table name to escape it according to the database dialect that is in use.

Comment: Yes entity name is also **Order**, is there any workaround to this problem? As this entity is in a third party library and we can't make changes to it.

Comment: I've checked the ANTLR grammar for HQL and can't find any evidence of an escaping mechanism so the only thing that I can think of if you can't rename the entity would be to use the Criteria API instead.