# Build query by hibernate language

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a query

```
List<Integer> ids = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery("SELECT l.id FROM likes l INNER JOIN liketoanswers lta ON l.id = lta.id AND lta.answer_id = :a_id")
                .setParameter("a_id",answer.getId())
                .list();
List<Like> likes = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer id : ids) {
    likes.add(findById(id));
}
return likes;
```

I want to make this query like .`createQuery("from Like l inner join fetch likes.answers la where la.id = answer.getId ..)`

but word Like is registered in sql and a dont want to change entity class name. 
I known that there a method to substitute class , but cannot find

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686412/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-hibernates-hql

Comment: Without commenting on other issues with this query, you can change entity name without changing class name, with `@Entity(name = "SomeName") public class Like { ...`