# unexpected token error in hibernate with Java

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have Route Entity class and when I'm going to fetch all the data from that table in HQL query I get an error for a only one column.

**Route.class :-**

```
@Entity
public class Route {

    @Id
    private long routeID;

    private String start;
    private String end;
    private String routeNo;
    private double startLat;
    private double startLon;
    private double endLat;
    private double endLon;
}
```

**DataFetch.Class :-**

```
public class DataFetch{

    public void FetchRoutes(){

        Query q = session.createQuery("select routeID,routeNo,start,end from Route ");
        List<Object[]> routes = (List<Object[]>) q.list();

        for (Object[] r : routes) {
            System.out.println("id: "+r[0]);
            System.out.println("No: "+r[1]);
            System.out.println("start: "+r[2]);
            System.out.println("end: "+r[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

In DataFetch.class if i remove "end" column from the query q there are no errors. but if i add end again as shown this question,it will give an error.
below I show my error as a screen shot.

[Click here to see my Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFIrV.png)

**What is the problem?**

Comment: `END` being a reserved word? try to quote it, like `"end"`...

Comment: "end" is probably a reserved word. Try escaping it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686412/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-hibernates-hql

Comment: end is a HQL/SQL Keyword, so you might need to escape it.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

End is a reserved keyword so you either escape it or use table alias in select

```
"select r.routeID, r.routeNo, r.start, r.end from Route r"
```

Answer (score 3):

End is probably a reserved word.

But, why not just use Hibernate for what it's worth, and skip the whole manual row mapping thing:

```
TypedQuery q = em.createQuery("select r from Route r", Route.class);
List<Route> routes = q.getResultList();
```

Example with em and typed query, since it gives a prettier result. The same can be done with session and a cast..

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try typed query! end is a reserved word. thanks again!

Comment: You need to use entitymanager instead of sessionfactory though. Might be easiest to just change your select clause to `select r`, and then the result will be  `List<Route>` (which you will need to cast).

Comment: ok.I will try that.I didn't know that method.I'm new to hibernate. Thanks again!