# HQL Reserved Keywords in query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I have two special words in my table and had no idea but later found out that they are reserved words. Tried to wrap them with single quotes and double quotes, didn't work and get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode cannot be cast to
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode

Anyone knows how to solve it?

```
Query query = session.createQuery("Update Routes set airline = :airline, "
        + "code = :code, from = :from, to = :to, airplaneid = :airplaneid, "
        + "price = :price, booked = :booked, activestatus = :activestatus"
        + " where code = :code ");
```

Comment: in your table or in your Entity?

Comment: Both, I guess. Tried to make the "from" to something like " 'from'" and same with "to". Did not work. @Y

Comment: try to use alias for entity in query. for example: `Update Routes r SET r.airline = :airline ...`

Comment: your error not say any thing about reserved keywords

Comment: Well, rename the columns in the table, and the fields in the entity. What's the problem in doing that?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686412/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-hibernates-hql