# Escape keywords from @where clause in Entity for Hibernate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, date, orm

I have an Entity class as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_MAIN" )
public class userDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_ID")
    private int userId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Where(clause = "CAST(START_DATE AS DATE) <= CAST(getDate() AS DATE)")
    private Set<userContractBasic> userContract=new HashSet<userContractBasic>();

}
```

I want to join this with `userContractBasic` entity with a where condition `START_DATE > current_date`. Here I want only date check required, not date-time check. So I've added `CAST` in `@where` clause.
But after adding `CAST` the query while fetching all results are :

```
SELECT  <fields>
FROM user_main um
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_contract uc ON um.user_id=uc.user_id
AND CAST(uc.START_DATE AS uc.DATE) <= CAST(getDate() AS uc.DATE)
```

The `DATE` keyword in `ON` clause is prepended with the table alias and its breaking the query.

Is there any way I can avoid it?

Comment: Im just guessing here but can you try to wrap Date between square brackets: [Date] ?

Comment: @Dimitri-  tried it already and it's not working. I am getting it as `uc.[DATE]`

Comment: Try the following: uc."DATE"

Comment: its getting cast as `CAST(uc.START_DATE AS 'DATE')`.  no table-alias there, still incorrect syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape reserved words in Hibernate's HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686412/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-hibernates-hql)

Comment: @Mick, thanks for the link and it was informative. But I am using JPA and my whole query will be something like `findAll()` and I think I need to fix it on my entity itself.

Answer (score 0):

you need not to specify AS keyword there 
just change your @Where with following

```
@Where(clause = "CAST(START_DATE) <= CAST(getDate())")
```

Comment: Thanks for showing interest in this question. But as mentioned in the question, I needed the `date` to be compared, not `datetime`. So this one won't work here.