# Workaround for java hibernate to update row in mySQL tables with reserved words as column names

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I need to connect to a legacy database with tables that have column names such as 'like'. Most logical way to fix this was to rename the columns, but the db admin does not want to perform any changes to the existing db.

Is there a way to workaround this to force hibernate to add backtick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various workarounds, depending on the context:

- For XML mapping files, enclose the keyword with quotes<sup>1</sup>.
- For Hibernate annotations, enclose the keyword with quotes<sup>2</sup>.
- You can tell Hibernate to quote all SQL identifiers with:

  ```
  hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
  ```

  in the Hibernate settings file.
- In HQL, you can escape *aliases* via a custom transformer; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5754720/139985 for an example.

References:

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-quoted-identifiers
- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/appendices/Configurations.html
- https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-use-database-reserved-keyword-in-hibernate/
- [How to escape reserved words in Hibernate's HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686412/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-hibernates-hql)

---

<sup>1 - Different sources say to use database-specific quotes or backticks which Hibernate supposedly knows how to translate.  I am not in a position to check this.  Both approaches could work.</sup>

<sup>2 - Apparently double quotes (escaped) and square brackets can be used.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Can you check try marking these settings as true?

```
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers = true
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions = true
```

**From Hibernate docs, I Quote:**(https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/appendices/Configurations.html)

> **hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers** (e.g. ***true or false*** (default value))
>   Should all database identifiers be quoted.
>   
>   **hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions** (e.g. ***true or false*** (default value))
>   Assuming hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers is true, this allows the global quoting to skip column-definitions as defined by `javax.persistence.Column`, `javax.persistence.JoinColumn`, etc, and while it avoids column-definitions being quoted due to global quoting, they can still be explicitly quoted in the annotation/xml mappings.

Comment: @Stephen C 's answer seems to have more details than my answer with reference articles.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it seems setting hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers = true does not work in my current setup, but maybe there are conflict in my config. 

Anyway I manage to solve by following one of @Stephen C's suggested articles regarding use of square brackets for [column_name] annotations...