# QueryParameterException even if everything seems to be named properly

Tags: java, hibernate, parameters

I'm debugging the following function:

```
public List<ImpPeriode> importPeriode(Integer type, Date dateDebut) {
    String sQuery = "from "+ImpPeriode.class.getCanonicalName()+" ip where ip.type = :type and ip.dateDebut > :dateDebut";
    Query query =  getSession()
            .createQuery(sQuery)
            .setParameter("type", type)
            .setParameter("dateDebut", dateDebut);
    return (List<ImpPeriode>) query.list();
}
```

The mapping for my ImpPeriode class is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping schema="importeloi">
    <class name="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.importation.ImpPeriode" table="imp_periode">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="periode_id" />
        </id>

        <property name="type" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="periode_type" not-null="true"/>
        </property>

        <property name="dateDebut" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="periode_datedeb" length="19" not-null="true"/>
        </property>

        <property name="dateFin" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="periode_datefin" length="19" not-null="true"/>
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

but somehow, I keep getting an error indicating an error in my parameter naming:

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [type]
```

I'm using Java 7 and Hibernate 3.6.10.

Obviously I'm missing something, but what?

**Edit:**

I changed the code in order to make the word "type" disappear:

```
public List<ImpPeriode> importPeriode(Integer periodeType, Date periodeDateDebut) {
    String sQuery = "from "+ImpPeriode.class.getCanonicalName()+" ip where ip.periodeType = :periodeType and ip.periodeDateDebut > :periodeDateDebut";
    Query query =  getSession()
            .createQuery(sQuery)
            .setParameter("periodeType", periodeType)
            .setParameter("periodeDateDebut", periodeDateDebut);
    return (List<ImpPeriode>) query.list();
}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping schema="importeloi">
    <class name="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.importation.ImpPeriode" table="imp_periode">
        <id name="periodeId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="periode_id" />
        </id>

        <property name="periodeType" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="periode_type" not-null="true"/>
        </property>

        <property name="periodeDateDebut" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="periode_datedeb" length="19" not-null="true"/>
        </property>

        <property name="periodeDateFin" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="periode_datefin" length="19" not-null="true"/>
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Sadly, I get exaclty the same error.

Comment: Your entity has an attribute name type? Is it working if you hardcode the integer instead of setting the parameter?

Comment: @aksappy I get another error: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1

Comment: Did you do `setParameter(0, periodeDateDebut)`?

Comment: You mean `setParameter(1, periodeDateDebut)`, Iguess. Yes, I tried, but it's throwing the exception on the setParamter on `type`, so changing the setParameter on `dateDebut` won't solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I meant - hard code the type in query to an integer of your choice and then set the periodDateDebut.. I did a similar setup in my local to see whether I can replicate, without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type is a reserved word in HQL. If you rename your field it should work.

Comment: And to add to your point, If `type` needs to be used, there is an answer that can help write a custom `alias`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686412/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-hibernates-hql

Comment: I changed my code, but it isn't solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to declare the mapping file in the Spring application context. I knew it would be a silly memory lapse.

I have to say: the thrown exception and error message have nothing to do with the actual problem. It's really confusing.